# Simple GIT workflow for small website development by one

Tags: git, repository, workflow, git-push, git-remote

I'm new to git, trying to get my head round it.

So I'm developing a simple website locally and tracking it with git and want a remote repo on the public facing server to be the live site, to which I can push the master branch whenever I'm ready to do so.

I thought the following would work but it doesn't.

Public server I did this:

```
/home/mysite/git init --bare
```

Local (development machine) I did this:

```
git init
git add index.html (contains hello world)
git commit -am "initial commit"
git remote add website ssh://mysiteuser@mysite:myport 
git remote (outputs: website)
```

Now I want to publish this to the 'website'

```
git push website
```

And I get:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream website master
```

So I try:

git push --set-upstream website master

And I get:

```
fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax
```

I looked in man git pull and it sheds no light for me.

Am I doing this right but missing something in the push command? Or have I misunderstood something more fundamental.

TIA!

Comment: `git push website -u master:refs/heads/master`.

Comment: can you share the o/p of .git/config file. hoping you are sitting on master branch. $ git push origin master is generally used.

Comment: This is the local git config file content (edited for privacy) [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
 precomposeunicode = true
[remote "website"]
 url = ssh://website@myserver:myport/home/website/website.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/website/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = website
 merge = refs/heads/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect my original question was misunderstood by those good people who tried to help me. To re-iterate - I want to have the development repo locally, and when I 'push' have it automatically update the files on my web server so that the website project is pushed live on my whim.

Here's how I've done it...

ON REMOTE (WEB SERVER)

```
mkdir website
cd website
git init
// here's the clever bit!
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
```

(That last line does two things. It stops the remote repository from complaining about an update to the checked out branch - and it also checks it out straight away. Other methods commonly used add a 'hook' to do the latter part of the process.)

ON LOCAL DEVELOPMENT (MY LAPTOP)

```
cd ~/website-dev-folder
git init
git remote add website ssh://my_user_name@mysever.com:my_port/home/website
git add some_file.html
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push -u website master
```

Henceforth after any local change is finalised and merged into master, to publish the master branch live it's a simple:

```
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple and follow the small Steps to proceed:

- Install git on the remote server say some ec2 instance
- Now create a project folder 
     $mkdir project.git

  $cd project and execute $git init --bare
  Let's say this project.git folder is present at your ip with address inside home_folder/workspace/project.git, forex- ec2 - /home/ubuntu/workspace/project.git

Now in your local machine, `$cd` into the project folder which you want to push to git execute the below commands:

```
 git init .
 git remote add origin username@189.14.666.666:/home/ubuntu/workspace/project.git
 git add .
 git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Below is an optional command but found it has been suggested as i was working to setup the same thing

```
 git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"

 git pull origin master
 git push origin master
```

This should work fine and will push the local code to the remote git repository.

To check the remote fetch url, cd project_folder/.git and cat config, this will give the remote url being used for pull and push operations.

You can also use an alternative way, after creating the project.git folder on git, clone the project and copy the entire content into that folder. Commit the changes and it should be the same way. While cloning make sure you have access or the key being is the secret key for the remote server being used for deployment.

Comment: Despite the output/result of the final git push origin master being "Everything up-to-date" - none of the files in the local repo are being pushed to the server. Nothing changes on the server at all. I added another file - staged and commit then ran git push origin master and got: Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 327 bytes | 327.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://mysite.co.uk:myport/home/mysite
   cf9c485..f40a475  master -> master

Comment: Additional. I ran through the procedure outlined in this answer on a local machine with completely new empty folder structure using a relative path as opposed to ssh. When I got to the 'git pull origin master' command (which I ran on equiv of local machine) I got: fatal: couldn't find remote ref master NEWLINE fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly. The next command seemed to work OK ending with * [new branch] master -> master but on checking the 'remote' there's no sign of any files having been added. On the 'remote' a git status gives: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree.

Comment: can you post the o/p of config file from .git, i had asked this earlier to understand it better